# Sequelize "separate: true" won't work on nested include statements

Tags: mysql, node.js, model, sequelize.js

I cannot get sequelize "separate: true" option to work on nested include statements. For my code snippets I will remove the bulk of the code and show a small example of whats going wrong in my large query.

Context: Patient has many Scenarios, and Patient has many Characteristic.

Using nested include which does not work:

```
    const scenario = await Scenario.findByPk(scenario_id, {
        include: [{
            model: Patient,
            attributes: [ 'name' ],
            required: true,
            include: [{
                model: Characteristic,
                separate: true,
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Without nesting the include (does work and uses same table association):

```
    const scenario = await Patient.findByPk(1, {
        include: [{
            model: Characteristic,
            separate: true,
        }]
    });
```

The portion of the mysql query that is causing the issue is this:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `characteristic_id`, `type`, `value`, `patient_id` FROM `Characteristic` AS `Characteristic` WHERE `Characteristic`.`patient_id` IN (NULL);
```

As you can see, when the include statement is nested, it compares patient_id to null. This does not make sense to me at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Are "separate" calls not supposed to be nested? And if so what is the best method for making huge queries, without separate sequelize generates a very complex list subquery inner joins, which is causing the queries to take THIRTEEN seconds for just 1100 lines of json.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the attributes option. If you have an attributes array to only pull certain columns and you don't include the parent object's primary key in the attributes array like this:

```
attributes: [ 'primary key name' ],
```

then it will search for the child objects using a null foreign key and will return a empty array.